# I am unable to style a page using max-width media query

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries, display

I am practicing to code. Trying to make the grubhub webpage. Having trouble with the max-width media query.

Below is my code

```
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    div.displayFood h2 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    .order {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
  }
```

I understood that it's a lot of codes. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missed close bracket on class `.hide`

This is the reason why nothing works after this class

```
.hide {
  display: none;
} /*<---- this is missing*/
  
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .hero {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful :) You can mark this answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Media Query for device width < 800px would be`@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {...}`